# Redirect folders to root but not subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect two specific folders but keep the subfolders as is?

e.g.

Lettering > Redirect to root (mysite.com)

- subfolder1 > keep the same
- subfolder2 > keep the same

Type > Redirect to root (mysite.com)

- subfolder1 > keep the same
- subfolder2 > keep the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch ^/lettering/?$ /
RedirectMatch ^/type/?$ /
```

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?lettering/?$ / [L,R]
RewriteRule ^/?type/?$ / [L,R]
```

This will redirect a request for `http://mysite.com/lettering/` to `http://mysite.com/`, but *will not redirect* a request like `http://mysite.com/lettering/subfolder2/`.

Comment: Now I have two questions: What if the folders are in another folder (mysite.com/v3/lettering - same thing for type) and where should the htaccess folder be?

Comment: @ChristopherBurton 1. Then you'd change instances of `lettering` to `v3/lettering`, etc. 2. These directives would go in the htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: So the RewriteRule should be: RewriteRule ^/?/v3/lettering/?$ / [L,R]

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thank you, I appreciate you taking the time out to help.